# Integrating Facebook with Jekyll blog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, blogs, facebook-opengraph

**Goal:**

I want to share articles from my Jekyll generated blog which is hosted on GitHub to Facebook with all the relevant info (titles, thumbnails, etc.)

**Questions:**

1. Do I need to create a Facebook app to be able to use the meta data I've included in the header in blog?
2. If I do need to create an app, what kind of features do I need to request to for it to work?
3. Would it be possible to use my business FB business page instead of an app and substitute the app ID for the admin ID?

**Current Status:**

FB page:
https://www.facebook.com/carolyncodes/

My blog:
http://carolyncodes.com/

Comment: If you are planning to use the [Share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) then the data you need is already there. (for instance app id is required)

Comment: Thank you. I found out that I really only needed the meta tags and not the app id. Like you said. :)